# Parametro Procedimiento almacenado Nulo

Tags: mysql, mysqli, stored-procedure

mi pregunta es la siguiente, lo que buscaba hacer era hacer un procedimiento que pudiera recivir sí y no parametros como CALL reg('cliente', 0, 10, null, null).

y se suponía que si está como nulo search me marcaría todos los datos, pero realmente me muestra nada, sirve cuando le pongo CALL reg('cliente', 0, 10, 'nombre', 'carlos') si aparece un valor

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero quisiera que si punto nulo search me muestre todos y no sé como hacerlo :c

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `reg`(
    IN `act` VARCHAR(50),
    IN `start` INT,
    IN `end` INT,
    IN `search` VARCHAR(50),
    IN `searchValue` VARCHAR(100)
)
LANGUAGE SQL
NOT DETERMINISTIC
CONTAINS SQL
SQL SECURITY DEFINER
COMMENT ''
BEGIN
    IF act = 'cliente' THEN
        SELECT cliente.id_cliente, cliente.name_cliente, cliente.id_estatus FROM cliente 
            WHERE CASE search
                    WHEN 'id' THEN cliente.id_cliente = IFNULL(searchValue, null)
                    WHEN 'nombre' THEN cliente.name_cliente LIKE CONCAT('%', searchValue, '%')
                    WHEN 'estatus' THEN cliente.id_estatus = IFNULL(searchValue, null)
                END
            ORDER BY cliente.id_cliente LIMIT start, end;
    END IF;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

después de mucha reflexión creo que llegué a un resultado

```
BEGIN
    CASE tarjet
        WHEN 'cliente' THEN 
            IF search IS NOT NULL THEN
                SELECT * FROM cliente 
                    WHERE CASE search
                        WHEN 'id' THEN cliente.id_cliente = IFNULL(param, cliente.id_cliente)
                        WHEN 'nombre' THEN cliente.name_cliente LIKE IFNULL(CONCAT('%', param, '%'), '%%')
                        WHEN 'estatus' THEN cliente.id_estatus = IFNULL(param, cliente.id_estatus)
                    END
                    ORDER BY cliente.id_cliente LIMIT inicio, final;
            ELSE
                SELECT * FROM cliente ORDER BY cliente.id_cliente LIMIT inicio, final;
            END IF;
    END CASE;
END
```

Answer (score -3):

Creo que debías manejar ese valor null de otro modo, antes de llamar tu procedimiento porque si el parámetro de búsqueda es null no hay búsqueda realmente. Pero imaginemos que no puedes evitar un valor null, en ese caso quieres listar toda la tabla, pues imagino que puedes usar WHEN CASE null y listar todos los registros sin importar el valor del último parámetro de la forma cliente.id_cliente=*

Comment: El asunto es que ya no tengo nada que poner en esa opción, ¿lo puedo dejar en blanco si pongo alguna?